# How to keep element size while WPF zoom in and out?

Tags: wpf, size, zooming, element, fixed

I faces the problem of keep the same width and height of the element but change the position when it zoom. Like zooming a map with pin, when you zoom, the map is enlarged but the pin keep in the relative position with the same size. Could anyone know how to achieve it?